# JXL Hide a Sheet on creation

Tags: java, excel, jxl

JXL Hide a Sheet

My requirement is like this

I need to create a sheet and make it hidden ( using JXL API) .

Later from the program I would populate values in to the hidden sheet which is a reference for another sheet.

Can some one tell me how to hide a sheet using JXL API.

Regards,

N.S.Balaji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling:

sheet.[getSettings()](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Sheet.html#getSettings%28%29).[setHidden(true)](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/SheetSettings.html#setHidden%28boolean%29);